# Simple AJAX HTTP GET using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-get

I am very new to jQuery and AJAX,I am trying following code,just simple http get request.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src = "jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src = "app.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.get("http://google.com", function(data, status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and I am getting following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.

Please help me what am I missing.

Comment: It is called Same Origin Policy restrictions related to resource access

Comment: It states to enable CORS on server side,but in my case it's just `http:://google.com`. How should I do it?

Comment: You can not consume google data untill they will allow urs site to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same origin policy will not let you access resources hosted on a different server. In your case, if the target system is not under your control, you can look at utilities like [jsonp](http://json-p.org/) which can help you fire cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

So according to SOP which is same origin policy  Under this policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin same origin means same URL Scheme , Host name and Port number. to get over this you can use like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://google.com",
    dataType: "jsonp"},
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
})
```

Read more on JSONP.

Answer (score -1):

It is simply cross domain request which you are making from your application, things you have to make sure to avoid this error,

```
1) Enable cors in your application to make a cross domain application.
2) You can use JSONP while making your request to cross domain instead of GET.
```

Please go through this link you will get more detail about the "CORS"
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors